# Does anyone know this song from Naruto Shippuden that plays in this video?

Tags: naruto, music

I've been looking for the name of this OST, but I haven't had any luck finding it. It's the first one played [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liotuj4dArU). It's also played on the 6:07 mark in [episode 343](http://gogoanime.tv/naruto-shippuden-episode-343).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an unreleased OST titled (for now) as "**[Konoha Peace Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW1ppyOGg2E&list=PL3EFB5805B9DDB6BA)**".

It is said that the soundtrack will be included in the Naruto Shippūden: OST III.